# Mathematical operations on sparse-value columns in Pandas produces an error

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

In pandas, I have a dataframe where I need to generate two matrices of dummies, and then add the columns of one dummy matrix to the other. However, it appears that pandas does not support mathematical operations with two columns of sparse values.

```
# illustrative example
import pandas as pd

mat = [['cat','black',18],
       ['dog','brown',12],
       ['cat','tabby',9],
       ['mouse','brown',0.2]]
testframe = pd.DataFrame(mat, columns = ['animal','color','weight'])

# create a new dataframe of dummies with columns "cat", "dog", and "mouse"
animals = pd.get_dummies(testframe['animal'], sparse = True)

# the following does not create an error
animals['cat'] + 1

# this does
animals['cat'] + animals['dog']
```

When running the last line, I get the error `module 'pandas._libs.sparse' has no attribute 'sparse_add_uint8'`.

It appears that I can still perform scalar operations on sparse-valued columns; as mentioned, I can add a single number to such a column without issue. However, there are no results online that expand on the error message.

My first thought for a workaround is to simply convert to SciPy sparse matrices and then back to Pandas, but I would prefer to stick with Pandas if possible.

Comment: After playing around with this, I found that `animals = pd.get_dummies(testframe['animal'], sparse = True, dtype=int)` works.  The implementation of 'sparsity' in `pandas` has been in the state of development for sometime, so I'm not surprised that there are rough edges.  `get_dummies` by default uses `uint8` dtype.

Comment: I think a more typical approach would use dense, long-format multi-indexed series via `stack`

Comment: @hpaulj it does appear to work with the toy example that I have concocted on my personal machine, which uses pandas 1.3.4. However, I'm also trying to solve this with a massive dataset on a remote desktop with 1.4.4, and the same approach is giving me the error message `module 'pandas._libs.sparse' has no attribute 'sparse_add_int32'`. @Reinderien this might work, but I'm ultimately running a large regression that might not mesh well with a multi-index

Comment: Or it could be that `int` is `int32` on one machine and `int64` on the other.  I don't know the details, but the sparse produced by this `get_dummies` is a special `dtype`.  It isn't a `pandas.sparseArray`, and now a `scipy.sparse` object.

Comment: @hpaulj Wow, you were right; explicitly setting `dtype = np.int64` did get it working on the other machine. Rather odd. If you want to write this up as a solution, I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hpaulj, it appears that this can be solved by requiring `dtype = np.int64` when creating the dummy values. Hopefully, this will not be required in future versions of Pandas.